# Android WiFi Direct Demo Issues

Tags: android, p2p, android-wifi, android-wireless

im testing the new technology wifi direct and im having some issues using 
the wifi direct demo from the samples that come with the android-sdk.

So, I have two devices A and B, both with android 4.0.3.

First, from device A, I send a file to B. Nothing wrong here, B 
receives the file.

Then A disconnects from B.

Now, from device B I try to send a file to A.

But the device that receives the file is B, instead of A.

To fix, i need to turn off and on both devices...

Also, sometimes when i click disconnect and try to 
connect again, connection fails and i have to disable and 
enable wifi direct...

Anyone else experiencing this?

Is it because the new technology is not mature yet or maybe 
something wrong with my build/driver/etc or maybe this demoapp 
doesnt support two-way sharing. 
Any ideas and/or explanations would be apreciated.

Answer (score 5):

When providing a `WifiP2pConfig` instance to the `connect()` function, you can set the `groupOwnerIntent` property of this configuration object as follows:

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
config.deviceAddress = "...";                 // insert ip here
config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;
config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
manager.connect(..., config, ...);
```

From the [android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pConfig.html):

> This (the groupOwnerIntent) is an integer value between 0 and 15 where
>   0 indicates the least inclination to be a group owner and 15 indicates
>   the highest inclination to be a group owner.

Furthermore, the demo probably repeatedly sends the file to the same device because there is always made a socket connection to the ip-address obtained from:

```
WifiP2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress
```

If you would like to support bidirectional communication, the first step in setting this up would be sending the ip-address of the non group owner to the group owner.

As far as the disconnect/reconnect problem goes, I seem to have the same inconsistencies with Android 4.0.2 devices.

Comment: The problem is that the GO ip address was the same always. Its the ip of the soft AP not the device itself ip, and looks like it is hardcoded on ICS... Please correct me if I`m wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying for a while to transfer files between two devices using wifi direct. I have use the Android SDK WifiDirectDemo as base. My experience:

GO address is always the same (at least in Samsung Nexus), but this is not really a problem, because you can use this to know who is the server (or client).

Another strange thing was that MAC address of devices were different when you got it from Android WifiManager and when you read it from "/proc/net/arp" file.

At the end I did it, and you can see the code [here](https://github.com/ahmontero/wifi-direct-demo).

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Great, i will have a look on it. Which build you are using for ur nexus?

Comment: Both Nexus were using Android 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with the same problem lately. I suppose this is an OS issue. To give you a brief background, I have installed Wi-Fi Direct application to both devices with different OS versions, one with OS 4.0.1 and one with OS 4.0.2. The connection fails from time to time when I disconnect and reconnect the devices. It goes same while searching for devices too. But the thing is, this only happens on the device with OS 4.0.2. Other device does not crash or disconnect.

While searching for that problem, I have found the links below. People discussed about that and they share the same idea. Apparently this is an OS 4.0.2 issue. I am not sure if it is the same for OS 4.0.3 but there is no problem with the previous version OS 4.0.1 for sure.

Here are the links:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24402

http://osdir.com/ml/android-platform/2012-01/msg00226.html

Comment: Im using 4.0.3 on both devices (Xperia mini). Search on devices are working fine. Reconnection always fails, i have to disable/enable wifi-direct every time i want to reconnect...

Comment: I see. I have not upgraded my OS yet and I was hoping that I won't have these problems with the new version. But apparently this problem will continue until Google introduces new features for Wi-Fi Direct.

Comment: It seems like a stack problem, also I noticed the IP that is given to the group owner is hardcoded on ICS ("192.168.49.1"). Check these links: [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/e46707883c248aed/4f09d509947b284b?hl=pt-BR&lnk=gst&q=wifi+direct+android#4f09d509947b284b) [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/9084aad2db6a33e2/6b432b449d20485f?hl=pt-BR&lnk=gst&q=wifi+direct+android#6b432b449d20485f).

Comment: There are some other problems about selecting the group owner. Seems like there is no consistency on this selection. Thanks for the links!